# Drupal unique login

Tags: drupal, authentication, single-sign-on

I have two instances of Drupal on same server instance 1 and instance 2  with different databases. I want to do following functionality so I will go ahead for my work.

1. Unique login for both instances. When I login to instance 1 then if I open url of instance 2 on same browser then it should not ask for me login.
2. While any add/update operation perform on instance 1 or instance 2 then user table should be updated in both databases.

Please let me know so I will go ahead.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't say which version of Drupal you are using?

Comment: in completely different domains or sub domains ? example.com and forums.example.com sso ?

Comment: Sorry for that i am using Drupal 6.
The website are on same server but with different files and different databases.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If there you I would utilize Drupal`s openid (oAuth) technologies. That could be done with some minor coding or even a couple of modules.
That would allow you  to create linked accounts but different profiles for each site. You would have a setup like it is here at stackexchange network and some additional functionality.

**EDIT**: There is a module called [OpenID URL](http://drupal.org/project/openidurl).It will give your users ability to use their profile pages as OpenID URLs. You could do it with a just a tad of coding. 
Then you could simply copy "Loin with OpenID" URL form your other site and name it "Create joined account..." or something like that.

You could use oAuth technology if you want more advanced connections.

There is also a possibility to create a multisite website.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for reply. Can you please tell me how can i handle login for two instances?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this module yet, but it sounds promising, to solving your first part of the problem: [project bakery](http://drupal.org/project/bakery).

> Bakery provides a "single sign on" feature for Drupal based sites that
>   are on the same second-level domain (i.e. example.com,
>   subsite.example.com, subsite2.example.com). It could also provide
>   support for any other website that implements the same web cookie,
>   xmlrpc, and POST methods.

For the second part I'm very interested in a solution. The only thing I can come up with at the moment, is some kind of RSS feeds. I know you can create nodes based on that.